# Como mostrar los datos de una tabla pivot en laravel

Tags: laravel

estoy realizando un calendario con fullcalendar en Laravel, cuando agrego un evento, tengo un multiple select en el que muestro los usuarios de la bbdd y selecciono los que deseo asignar a ese evento, al agregar el evento, se guarda en una tabla pivot llamada evento_user el id del evento que he creado y el id de los usuarios que he seleccionado. Al hacer click en el evento creado deseo que se muestre un select multiple con los usuarios asignados a ese evento. Solo consigo meter todos los registros de la tabla pivot en vez de los registros que coinciden con el id del evento.

**Este es el código de la vista**

```
<select multiple class="form-control" id="participantes2">
                            @foreach ($userEvents as $userEvent)
                                <option value="{{$userEvent->name}}" disabled>{{$userEvent->name}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
```

**Este es el código del controlador**

```
$users = User::all();
    
    $userEvents = DB::table('users')->select('users.name')->leftJoin('evento_user','users.id','=','evento_user.user_id')->get();

    return view ('eventos.index', compact('users','userEvents'));
```

Comment: ¿Tienes los modelos creados así como las relaciones definidas?

Comment: Si, tengo lo que es la query ya , ahora me falta recoger el id del evento para pasarlo en la query

Comment: Te pregunto sobre los modelos y relaciones por que considero asi sería mas simple

Comment: Sisi, estan hechos.

Answer (score 0):

Si ya tienes la relación podrias aplicar algo como.

$users = User::with('userEvents')
->get();

Esto ya depende el nombre que hayas asignado a tu relación

y mostrarlos asi

```
foreach($users as $user)
{{$user->name}}
    foreach($user->userEvents as $events)
     {{$events->name}}
    endforeach
endforeach
```